# How Did Third Eye Blind Get Translated As 心灵蒙蔽合唱团?

Tags: translation

I don't often see a lot of foreign bands names translated but came across this:

[网易云音乐](http://music.163.com/#/artist?id=78230)

> 心灵蒙蔽合唱团
>
> Third Eye Blind

- How Did Third Eye Blind Get Translated As 心灵蒙蔽合唱团?

合唱团 means chorus, does it not, they're certainly not a chorus either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think it's a mistranslation.  合唱团 means chorus, where 乐队 means band.    As why it's called / translated as "心灵蒙蔽":

> 心灵 - soul / spirit.  As eyes are called windows of the soul, 心灵 is
>   used insteads of 眼.  Also see Ampersand's comment for connotations on
>   third eye.
>
> 蒙蔽 - clouded / covered.  Nothing's wrong here

As the direct translation - 第三只眼失明乐队 doesn't sounds quite right (I laughed reading it), 心灵蒙蔽乐队 might be a more valid translation

EDIT: thanks to leo4jc, "瞎心眼樂隊" is even more catchy

Comment: Definitely "band" should be translated as 樂隊! If I were to translate it, I will go for 瞎心眼樂隊. Shorter, more catchy. 心眼 might retain the tie to eye and the new age meaning to the soul/heart. My two cents.